# Subtracting binary with numbers of different lengths

Tags: binary

I am trying to solved:   1111 – 10010 (binary)

I would like to use two's compliment to solve it. I realize that the answer will be negative, but I don't know how to get it.  I tried putting a zero before the first number (01111) to give the numbers equal number of 1s and 0s.  Also, how will I know the answer is negative?

```
    01101
  + 00001
____________
    01110  <-- two's compliment

 01110
+01111
________
 11101      //this isn't right
```

Comment: I suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is to beak it into small steps.

My first assumption is that you are trying to solve 15 (1111 (binary)) - 18 (10010 (binary))

I find the easiest way to do subtraction in  two's complement is by the  [method of complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements) which is instead of trying to subtract the positive 18 from the positive 15 ( +15 - (+18)), we instead add negative 18 to positive 15 ( +15 + (-18) ). This has the same result but is easier to do in two's compliment ( note: you can't do this if your number system does not have negative numbers)

So we have to take the number 15 and -18 and [convert them into two's complement numbers](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/dtotc.html). Since 18 is represented in binary with 5 bits we need to use at least 6 six bit to represent -18 in twos complement.

To convert -18 into two's complement we take 18 in two's complement 010010 flip those bits (turn the 0s into 1s and 1s into 0s) 101101, and then to add one to the flipped bits using [binary addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Addition)

```
      1      (carried digits)
  101101     (-19 (flipped 18 ))
+ 000001     (1)
_________
  101110     (-18)
```

To convert 15 into two's complement we take 15 in binary (1111) and then we add zeros on the left until it has the same amount of digits as -18 (101110) 001111

Now that we both numbers in two's complement we can add them together using [binary addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Addition)

```
   111       (carried digits)
  001111     (15)
+ 101110     (-18)  
_________
  111101     (-3)
```

This give us -3 in two's complement which is the correct answer (15 - 18 = -3).

You can learn about two's complement looking at the [twos complement wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)